# Ruby - How to filter an array of hashes by one value and then return true if other value matches input?

Tags: ruby, enumerable, hash

I'm working on what I thought was a simple Code Wars problem but I'm having trouble using enumerables to solve this problem.

This is my data array

```
data = [
  {age: 40, sex: :m},
  {age: 24, sex: :f},
  {age: 56, sex: :m},
  {age: 45, sex: :m},
  {age: 23, sex: :f} 
]
```

And the problem

*Write a method so that it returns true if all of the items matching the sex value have ages greater than the value provided.*

method should be something like

```
def check_ages?(data, sex, older_than)

 #Select all hashes matching param(sex) and then check if remaining age values are      greater than param(older_than) returning true if so

end
```

check_ages?(data, :f, 22) # should be true

check_ages?(data, :m, 50) # should be false

I've been going crazy trying to use nested select to filter hashes and if else to match age value... All help would be appreciated

PS Im a relative newbie with ruby, sure this a fairly dumb question...just cant figure out the syntax

Comment: Here's a hint: use [Enumerable#all](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F): `data.all? {???}`.

Comment: data.all? { |d| d[:sex] != sex || d[:age] > age_is_older_than }                                                                    Your right, works great:) Thanks Cary

Comment: Good for you Conner.  Always best to work it out yourself, even if you need to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: A small point: while I too prefer short names for local variables within blocks (after all, how long do you have to remember what they stand for?), consider using something that reminds you of the data type of the elements you are processing (if they are all of the same type), such as `h` for hash, `a` for array, `s` for string, etc.) You have `data.all? {|d|..`, but you don't need to be reminded that `d` is an element of `data`.  `data.all? {|h|..` contains some additional information.  This is purely stylistic, so not everyone would agree.  Just my $0.02.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is all you need:

```
def check_ages?(data, sex, older_than)
  raise ArgumentError, "'sex' must equal ':m' or ':f'" unless [:m, :f].include? sex
  data.all? {|h| h[:sex] != sex || h[:age] > older_than}
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def data.all_older_than? age, sex: nil
  ( sex ? select { |e| e[:sex] == sex } : self ).all? { |e| e[:age] > age }
end

data.all_older_than? 30
#=> false

data.all_older_than? 30, sex: :male
#=> true
```

Comment: A weakness, I think: data.all_older_than? 30, sex: :female # => true, data.all_older_than? 30, sex: :neither # => true. (That observation caused me to modify my own answer a little.)  Also, this method is only available to this instance of Array, which would be a limitation if we wanted to apply it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It think it is easiest to read if you split the logic up into two parts: First `select`, then `all?`

```
def check_ages?(data, sex, older_than)
  data.select{|person| person[:sex] == sex }
        .all?{|person| person[:age] > older_than}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortest and easiest way

```
    def check_ages?(data, sex, age_is_greater_than)
    data.select { |h| h[:sex] == sex}.all? { |a| a[:age] > age_is_greater_than }
    end
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a little simpler, but may work for you here

```ruby
def check_ages?(data, sex, older_than)
  for p in data
    if p[:sex] == sex
      if !(p[:age] > older_than)
        return false
      end
    end
  end
  return true
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Christopher Hunt, I was over complicating things with enumerables that I obviously havn't grasped yet. Amazing how simple some solutions can be..forest for the trees etc ;)

Comment: Using inject doesn't seem idiomatic here. select->all? makes a lot more sense to me. (I'm not the downvote. Just pointing that out.)

Comment: You're right, thank you. I don't know why I included that, but it has been removed.